# Google plus comments box does not load in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-plus

Here is the page: http://www.techwhack.co/google-dumbs-chrome-apps-policy-update-49376/

The Google+ comment box loads fine in Chrome and IE but doesn't load in Firefox. If I try to use the Dev Tools I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: gapi is not defined
```

How to fix it?

Comment: What version of Firefox and OS?  It just worked for me on OSX with FF 26.0.

Comment: Firefox 26 on Windows 8.1.

Comment: It's working for me in Firefox 26.0 on Windows 8.1. Does it happen every time?